# gnuplot: 3d scatter plot with circles

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to do a 3d plot, where I want each point to be with my choice of color/shape/shade. The fact is that I want to use the colour palettes from [here](https://github.com/Gnuplotting/gnuplot-colorbrewer).

Lets say my data is like this --

```
0   0   0
0   0   1
0   1   0
0   1   1
1   0   0
1   0   1
1   1   0
1   1   1
```

and my gnuplot command looks like this --

```
set style fill transparent solid 0.75 noborder
set style circle radius screen 0.01
splot "data.out" with circles linecolor rgb "blue"
```

and I am getting this plot --

[image]

as you can see, there is no circle, every point is `+`.

How do I draw with circles ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To draw with circles you need

```
splot "data.out" linecolor "blue" pointtype 6
```

To get circle try type 6 or 7. Size of circle can be changed by adding option `pointsize 2` (number is value of size)